# CSS: backdrop-filter blur-ed div's color goes to browser margin near the margin of browser, when rotated

Tags: css

I have a div with `backdrop-filter: blur(42px);` css. When I rotate it and set position to `right: -2rem;`, color of its below changes to browser margin color:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLFYA.png)
But when not rotated, the color doesn't change:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMOmb.png)

code:

```
#box {
       height: 200px;
       width: 200px;
       position: absolute;
       transform: rotate(-15deg);
       right: -2rem;
       top: 2rem;
}

#box::before {
       content: "";
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       border-radius: 20%;
       display: flex;

       z-index: -1;
       background: rgba(19, 254, 164, 0.7);
       box-shadow: 0 0px 100px rgba(19, 254, 164, 1);
}

.box2 {
       backdrop-filter: blur(42px);
       height: 110%;
       width: 110%;
       border-radius: 20%;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-40%, -40%);
       z-index: 999999;
}

<div>
     <div class="box1" id="box">
          <div class="box2"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: provide a reproducable code.

Comment: `.box2` style added and `#box` completed.